# Toggling classes with cloned divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, toggle

I have a drop down menu that returns results after a selection. The user can then click a link, cloning the dropdown menu, and choose another selection that will return more results. The structure of the results div is as follows:

```
<ul>
  <li class="red">
    <span> some html content</span>
  </li>
  <li class="red">
    <span> some html content</span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I would like the user to click an li and change the background color. The user should only be able to change the color of one li at a time. I am able to accomplish this first part using:

```
$("li.red, li.blue").live("click",function() {
      var $this, c;
      $this = $(this);
      c = $this.hasClass("red")
                ? {us: "blue", them: "red" }
                : {us: "red", them: "blue" };
       $("li." + c.us).removeClass(c.us).addClass(c.them);
       $this.removeClass(c.them).addClass(c.us);
    });
```

The problem is that when the user adds another selection (and the previous dropdown is cloned using jquery), and clicks an li in that results div, the previous selection is unselected. I want the user to be able to change the background of the li for the first set of results, as well as change the background for the second set of results. So each set of results would be able to toggle background colors between only that particular ul.

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this...

```
$("ul").on("click", "li", function() {
    $(this).parent().find("li").removeClass("red").addClass("blue");
    $(this).toggleClass("red").toggleClass("blue");
});
```

jsFiddle example... http://jsfiddle.net/L34pT/3/

Giving the ul a class name or ID would make sure it only affects the list in question.  It looks a little pointless, but I used `parent` and `find` so that you only have to change the `ul` selector if you do give it a class or ID, and it will still work.

Comment: Archer...that works like a charm for the cloned div selection. However, I want only one li to be selected per ul. Any suggestions?

Comment: What do you class as selected?  Is it red or blue (or something else)?

Comment: sorry red would be selected...so only one list item within each list would have the class red

Comment: I've updated it.  They're now all blue at start and you can select one to change it red.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `on()` instead of `live()`:

```
$(document).on("click","li.red, li.blue",function() {
      ...
});
```